# Google maps - Postcode plotting

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm struggling to find any up to date relevant information on how to achieve this effect in google maps. I was hoping someone knows more than me on the subject and could point me in the correct direction..

The problem:

- I need to plot X amount of pins on a map via a postcode.
- The second step is to enter my own postcode and product a list of the closest 5 postcodes plotted in step one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code will tell you the single closest zipcode to the one you enter in the box. I'm sure from here you can adapt it to give the top 5 results.

I was able to adapt the [Geocoding sample code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.768505,-111.853244);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        addPostCode('84101');
        addPostCode('84102');
        addPostCode('84103');
        addPostCode('84104');
        addPostCode('84105');
    }

    function addPostCode(zip) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            name: zip
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
        });
    }

    function checkZip(zip)
    {
        var distance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var index = 0;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                for(ix=0; ix< markers.length; ix++)
                {
                    var tmp = getDistance(results[0].geometry.location, markers[ix].position);
                    if (tmp < distance)
                    {
                        distance = tmp;
                        index = ix;
                    }
                }
                alert('nearest zipcode is :' + markers[index].name);
            }
        });
    }

    function getDistance(latlng1, latlng2)
    {
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = (latlng2.lat()-latlng1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;  // Javascript functions in radians
        var dLon = (latlng2.lng()-latlng1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(latlng1.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(latlng2.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km
        d = d * 0.621371192; // convert to miles
        return d;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="checkZip(getElementById('address').value)">
  </div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its very helpful.. Sorry when i say postcode, i mean the UK postcode.. :) Ill look up the docs a little more using your base.

Comment: nm it works as is with uk postcodes.. thanks for the help again.. you've basically done it for me..

Comment: I imagine it will work with any postcode that Google recognizes.

Comment: Absolutely top kudos for this example script. Straight out the box working! I (and I think others) owe you a drink.